# Can't find parameter with findFit NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I have a data list and a function being to be fitted to the data to get parameters of the function as below. I can't find the parameters a, b, c, d with different below methods. Can you help me to find the parameters?

```
Datafit = {{105., 0.472263}, {110., 0.665252}, {115., 0.909801}, {120., 
      1.21304}, {125., 1.58227}}

Model=Exp[a + b/x + c*x + d*x*x]
```

1st try

```
FitC = NMinimize[datafit, 
  Exp[a + b/x + c*x + d*x*x], {{a, -1.7}, {b, 
    3.57}, {c, -0.99}, {d, -3.38}}, x]
{A4, B4, C4, D4} = {a, b, c, d} /. FitC
```

2nd try

```
FitC2 = FindFit[datafit, Exp[a + b/x + c*x + d*x*x], 
  x, {{a, 10}, {b, 0}, {c, 0.99}, {d, 3.38}}]
```

3rd try

```
FitC3 = NonlinearModelFit[
   datafit, {Cox[a, b, c, d, x]}, {{a, 7}, {b, 80}, {c, 4}, {d, 1}}, 
   x, MaxIterations -> 10000];
```

Can you help me to find parameter a, b, c, d of the model for the given data set?

Comment: See below but I would like to make you aware that the form you have for `NMinimize` is not correct. You need to feed it a single function and it doesn't take starting values but does accept constraints. Try `nminFunction = Total@Map[(modelFun[#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 &, datafit]` and then `NMinimize[
 {
  nminFunction,
  9 < a < 10,
  -900 < b < -800,
  -.03 < c < -.02,
  0.00006 < d < 0.00008
  }, {a, b, c, d}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the logarithm of the model data and the model equation you will provide the fitting software with a simpler problem.

```
datafit = {{105., 0.472263}, {110., 0.665252}, {115., 
   0.909801}, {120., 1.21304}, {125., 1.58227}}
```

Log of the model data

```
datafitLog = Map[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} &, datafit]
```

Log of the model

```
logModel = a + b/x + x (c + d x)
```

Now attempt `NonlinearModelFit`

```
logFit = NonlinearModelFit[datafitLog, logModel, {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

The best fit parameters are:

```
logFit["BestFitParameters"]

{a -> 9.3317, b -> -882.677, c -> -0.0236506, d -> 0.0000732741}
```

It is easy to define a `fit` function:

```
fit[x_] := Exp[logFit[x]]
```

Visually the results look good

```
Show[
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 105, 125}, PlotStyle -> Black,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.4, 1.7}}],
 ListPlot[datafit, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.025], Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` parameters are identical to both the `logModel` and `model`.

```
fit2[x_] := 
 Evaluate[Exp[a + b/x + c x + d x^2] /. logFit["BestFitParameters"]]

Show[
 Plot[fit2[x], {x, 105, 125}, PlotStyle -> Black,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.4, 1.7}}],
 ListPlot[datafit, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.025], Blue}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Poor Resolution

This problem is poorly resolved. One can see this by examining the correlation matrix.

```
logFit["CorrelationMatrix"]
```

I have placed the output in a grid

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All the parameters have a correlation factor close to 1 or -1 indicating that the problem is poorly resolved.

Comment: You were too polite by not mentioning that attempting to fit 5 parameters (a, b, c, d, and error variance) with just 5 data points is just asking for trouble.  Also, by taking logs one ends up with a linear model and `LinearModelFit[datafitLog, {1/x, x, x^2}, x]` works without the need for starting values.

Answer (score 3):

The scaling of `x` is very poor. Try `x/100`instead of x and the option `Method -> "NMinimize"`which doesn't need startvalues.

```
datafit = {{105., 0.472263}, {110., 0.665252}, {115.,0.909801}, {120., 1.21304}, {125., 1.58227}}
mod = NonlinearModelFit[datafit, {Exp[a + b/x/100 + c*x/100 + d*x*x/100^2]}, { a , b , c ,d }, x, Method -> "NMinimize"]
Show[ListPlot[datafit], Plot[mod[x], {x, 105, 125}]]
```

[image]